# R easy date parsing

Tags: r, shiny

I have a dataset where `df$Date` has a format of `18-Sep-2016`, so not really useful. How could I easily convert this so I can use it in a `Shiny app` in `sliderInput`?

Comment: `?Date` would be a good place to start.

Answer (score 6):

The `anydate()` function of the anytime package was written for **exactly** that purpose: *easy and reliable parsing without a format* whereas all other packages require a format string, or a pre-selected function:

```
R> library(anytime)
R> anydate("18-Sep-2016")
[1] "2016-09-18"
R> class(anydate("18-Sep-2016"))
[1] "Date"
R>
```

`anydate` even works when the format changes:

```
R> anydate(c("18-Sep-2016", "2016-09-18", "2016/09/18", "20160918", "09/18/2018"))
[1] "2016-09-18" "2016-09-18" "2016-09-18" "2016-09-18" "2018-09-18"
R>
```

It also deals with `factor` types but as the focus is on `POSIXct` that currently requires to go via `anydate(anytime(...))` (but will be fixed as the issue has been reported [a few days ago](https://github.com/eddelbuettel/anytime/issues/44))

```
R> fv <- as.factor(c("18-Sep-2016", "2016-09-18", "2016/09/18", 
+                    "20160918", "09/18/2018"))
R> anydate(anytime(fv))
[1] "2016-09-18" "2016-09-18" "2016-09-18" "2016-09-18" "2018-09-18"
R>
```

Comment: Can I also pass it a factor of values? Or how would I update my data.frame with the new any date return values?

Comment: Yes it can -- for `anytime()` and `utctime()`.  For `anydate()` and `utcdate()` I have an open bug report where it _currently_ does not. Side effect of a recent code change making another part more robust.

Comment: Alright, so if I use `as.character(df$Date)` as parameter to `anydate()`, will it work?

Comment: Should work, but also see my edit.  Just hand it to `anytime()` as is, but then reclass as `Date`.

Answer (score 0):

You want to convert the text string to 'Date' object. Here's one way using lubridate package.

```
library(lubridate) 
ans <- as.Date(parse_date_time('18-Sep-2016',orders = 'dmy'))
print(ans)
# [1] "2016-09-18"
class(ans)
# [1] "Date"
```

Comment: Can I also pass it a factor of values? Or how would I update my data.frame with the new any date return values?

Comment: df$Date <- as.Date(parse_date_time(as.character(df$Date),orders = 'dmy'))